# How to detect if chrome (or any other app) is playing sound using bash/applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, audio, google-chrome

I am writing a script to turn off audio on my mac, but need to check if its coming from the browser or an app (say Spotify). Is there a way to detect which app is playing sound?